# Place is followed by time, but is it always?

Tags: time

What I mean is: in a sentence like "I go to school in the city centre every morning." the place must always precede the time.

I am looking at a sentence that says: "established in 2010 in London, this facility is characterized by its high-end equipment".

Would this sentence still be correct, or do the place and time need to be switched?

Comment: What makes you think place is followed by time?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is perfectly fine. The reversal of order puts more emphasis on "London" than on the date.

Even with your first sentence putting the time first would be possible: unusual, certainly, but if you wished to put strong emphasis on the place, eg:

> I go every morning to school in the city centre. Last week I three times had to battle my way through demonstrations.